# How to make jButton.setVisible() work instantaneously?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I've written a test program with making the jButton invisible and visible:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Blink
{
    private JButton btn;
    private static JFrame f;

    public static void delay(int ms)
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(ms);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ex)
        {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }

    public Blink()
    {
        f = new JFrame("Blink");
        f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        btn = new JButton("Click me and I'll blink!");
        f.add(btn);
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                buttonClicked();
            }
        });

        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void buttonClicked()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            delay(300);
            btn.setVisible(false);
            delay(300);
            btn.setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Blink();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the jButton does not blink. And when the buttonClicked() function is changed, so that the jButton is set invisible 5 times and is not set visible back, the jButton disappears only when the for-loop finishes. How to make the jButton disappear an reappear instantaneously?

Comment: 1) Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix. 2) Rather than have a button 'blink' in visibility, why not simply change an icon?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use Thread.sleep method in Swing Thread (all listeners are called in Event Dispatcher Thread - EDT). To achieve blinking you must use `javax.swing.Timer` class. For more information look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Here is your reworked example:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Blink {
    private JButton btn;

    private JFrame f;

    public void delay(int ms, boolean show) {
        Timer timer = new Timer(ms, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                btn.setVisible(show);
                btn.getParent().revalidate();
                btn.getParent().repaint();
            }
        });
        timer.setRepeats(false);
        timer.start();
    }

    public Blink() {
        f = new JFrame("Blink");
        f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        btn = new JButton("Click me and I'll blink!");
        f.add(btn);
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                buttonClicked();
            }
        });

        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void buttonClicked() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i += 2) {
            delay(300 * i, false);
            delay(300 * (i + 1), true);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Blink();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

For some complicated layouts, call `setVisible(false)` may have side-effects. In this case the [CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) with your component and an empty panel should be used.

Here is the variant with `CardLayout`

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Blink {

    private static final String BUTTON_CARD = "button";

    private static final String EMPTY_CARD = "empty";

    private JButton btn;

    private JFrame f;

    private final CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();

    public void delay(int ms, boolean show) {
        Timer timer = new Timer(ms, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                cardLayout.show(btn.getParent(), show ? BUTTON_CARD : EMPTY_CARD);
                btn.getParent().revalidate();
                btn.getParent().repaint();
            }
        });
        timer.setRepeats(false);
        timer.start();
    }

    public Blink() {
        f = new JFrame("Blink");
        f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLayout(cardLayout);
        btn = new JButton("Click me and I'll blink!");
        f.add(btn, BUTTON_CARD);
        f.add(new JPanel(), EMPTY_CARD);
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                buttonClicked();
            }
        });

        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void buttonClicked() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i += 2) {
            delay(300 * i, false);
            delay(300 * (i + 1), true);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Blink();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it possible to simply write a function, which would make a delay, and not incorporating blinking into it?

Comment: No, it's not possible. At least without some third-party libs.

Answer (score 0):

As @Sergiy points out - make sure you're running from the EDT, and don't sleep on the EDT, use a swing timer instead.

To make your jButton appear "invisbile", you can do something like this:

```
public void setInvisible(jButton jb) {
  jb.setOpaque(false);
  jb.setContentAreaFilled(false);
  jb.setBorderPainted(false);
  jb.setText("");
}

// Assuming you have the original text saved in a variable
public void setRevisible(jButton jb) {
  jb.setOpaque(true);
  jb.setContentAreaFilled(true);
  jb.setBorderPainted(true);
  jb.setText(originalString);
}
```

Depending on if you want the button to be clickable when it's invisible, you can also add `btn.setEnabled(bool);`